# Getting type instead of value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to create a dropdownbox. I want to populate the list with values, but instead I get types in it.

ViewModel

```
 public class AdminViewModel
{
    ...

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddAdmin()
    {
        DataAccessLayer.DoloContext col = new DataAccessLayer.DoloContext();

        List<Roles> list = new List<Roles>(col.Roles.ToList());
        AdminViewModel viewMod = new AdminViewModel();                         

        viewMod.Roles = new SelectList(list);

        return View(viewMod);
    }
```

View

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Roles, (SelectList) Model.Roles, "RoleName", "Choose") 
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I get in my dropdownlist is `AuthSys.Models.Roles`

What am I doing wrong?
I have tried compare to the examples I can find here, but in the end, I keep getting the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try populating your `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as the following:

```
   viewMod.Roles = col.Roles
     .ToList()
     .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
       { 
          Value = x.Value,
          Text = x.Text
       }).ToList();
```

With `x.Value` and `x.Text` being your desired properties of Role.

Comment: When I do that, I get the message that an object of type List cannot be converted to one of type selectList

Answer (score 1):

Assumed that you have `Roles` class in data source like this:

```
public class Roles
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to get selected value from `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, do the following steps:

1) Create additional property which will hold selected value in viewmodel.

```
public class AdminViewModel
{
    public int SelectedRoleId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

2) Bind the option list into `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property like this:

```
public ActionResult AddAdmin()
{
    DataAccessLayer.DoloContext col = new DataAccessLayer.DoloContext();
    var viewMod = new AdminViewModel();   

    List<Roles> list = col.Roles.ToList();

    viewMod.Roles = list.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
        Text = x.RoleName,
        Value = x.RoleId
    }).ToList();

    return View(viewMod);
}
```

3) Finally, bind selected value property and option list to [`DropDownListFor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_SelectExtensions_DropDownListFor__2_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Web_Mvc_SelectListItem__System_String_) helper, also no need to convert `Roles` option list into `SelectList` because `Roles` already has type of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRoleId, Model.Roles, "Choose")
```